# Prometheus: 0 offset counter

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Given a Prometheus Counter object with monotonically increasing values, how can I generate a graph where the values begin at 0 for the start of the range in grafana and are grouped by label?

Pseudo formula (how I imagine it. I could be wrong)

```
foreach(label) plot(events - min_in_window(events)) # within windows
```

The result should be a monotonically increasing function, where values are offset to 0 at the beginning of the window. 1 event should have an identical increase in the resulting function/graph.

Comment: Are you using Grafana for visualization?

Comment: yes. I am using grafana for visualization

Comment: I'm not really sure if I got the question right. To offset the counter to 0 you can use rate and irate functions (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate).

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. The rate and irate functions do not offset the data to 0 and maintain the count proportional to the window. I.e reset the counter. I'm simply looking to get "there were x counts in this window" which rate does not accomplish

Answer (score 0):

This is fresh from the owen, so perhaps it needs some dressing up.
`my_metric - max_over_time(((timestamp(my_metric) <= bool (${__from} / 1000)) * my_metric)[$__range:1m])`

[image: Original counter plus the same one offset to 0]

Deficiency: Won't work for counter resets. For that to work `increase()` should be used in some place, but wasn't able to figure that out.

TBD:

- `<= bool (${__from} / 1000))` needs polishing. Now it just happens to work, but perhaps there's a better, more robust way to pinpoint the first timestamp.
- `[$__range:1m]` needs polishing. The second part, interval, probably depends on scraping interval.

Didn't have time to work on TBDs. If you make it work for you, let us know the polished version.

Comment: I will try and let you know how this goes! thanks for the attempt.

Comment: I found `mymetric - min_over_time(mymetric[$__range])` works pretty good. the above didn't work for me, but I might need to test it some more